# Отправить файл, имеющийся в base64, на сервер в "натуральном" виде

Tags: javascript, fileupload

Есть клиент, загружающий картинки на сервер.
Сервер недоступен для правок/доработок. Можно работать только с клиентом.

Перед отправкой картинки на сервер необходимо ее порезать/ресайзить и тд.
На выходе я получу base64 строку с данными файла.

Но со стороны сервера мне говорят, что картинки могут приниматься только в "натуральном" виде и никак иначе.

Пользуюсь [jquery ajaxform](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться что такое "натуральный" вид?

У `ajaxform` есть метод `beforeSubmit`, где можно пробежаться по данным перед отправкой, в объекте с файлом хранятся только метаданные типа `size`, `name`, `lastModified` и тд. Я не понимаю что именно отправляется на сервер.

Нашел [статью](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript), где показывается как base64 в blob конвертировать можно, но будет ли это "натуральным" видом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался в итоге.

Первым делом надо `base64` преобразовать в `blob`, как описано в [статье](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Затем создать объект `FormData` и отправить его через `XMLHttpRequest`

Пример:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'form input[type=file]', function(){

        var form = $('form').has($(this));

        // обычная отправка формы с файлами
        form.ajaxSubmit({
            complete: function(xhr){
                console.log(xhr);
                form.after(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        // извлечение файла в base64, преобразование в blob и отправка
        var input = this;
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var file = input.files[0],
                reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e){
                var fileData = e.target.result,
                    parts, type, base64Data;

                parts = fileData.split(',');
                type = parts[0];
                base64Data = parts[1];

                type = type.split(';')[0].split(':')[1];

                var formData = new FormData(),
                    blobImage = b64toBlob(base64Data, type);

                formData.append('xhr', 'works!');
                formData.append('image', blobImage, '123.jpg');

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', form.attr('action'), true);
                xhr.onload = function(e){
                    console.log('selfreaded ', xhr);
                    form.append(xhr.responseText);
                };
                xhr.send(formData);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

    });
});

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  return blob;
}
```

Отправляется 2 запроса. 1-й с помощью ajaxSubmit, второй через XHR/FormData.
У меня запросы отправлялись на php скрипт, где можно сравнить приходящие данные и сохранить файлики.